# Space between "function" and parenthesis in VS JS editor

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, editor

Why does Visual Studio JavaScript editor put a space between the "function" keyword and its following parenthesis ?

function foo () {
}

Is that some kind of cool convention ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a stylistic convention in Visual Studio. In the [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011285/space-after-function-in-visual-studio-ide) you could not change it, but you might find now you can: "Options -> Text Editor -> JScript -> Formatting"

Most refer the lack of space to [Douglas Crockford's javascript style guide](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

Comment: Here is another SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317870/how-do-i-stop-visual-studio-inserting-a-space-between-function-definition-and-im